# Configure IIS 10 to run an MVC2 project running dot net 4.0 on a Windows Server. Currently only returns 500

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have almost no experience with MVC, so hoping someone can help me.  I have already spent hours trying to configure IIS to run the applications.

The application runs fine in Visual Studio 2010. MVC2.  I can configure the publish and publish output seems to work fine.  I have configured IIS as I have many times, but more for a non-mvc .net application.

When uploading the application to the IIS directory I only receive 500 errors.  The IIS log doesn't give me much info to work with.

For grins, I created a new MVC project and uploaded that started app up to IIS and received same IIS 500 error.  This leads me to believe I've configured IIS incorrectly.  The only thing I'm confident of is I've screwed up somewher.

Any and all help is very appreciated!

Screenshot for Trace:

[click here to see screen shot of trace error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxgVH.png)
[Detailed trace Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sQqD.png)

Comment: "The IIS log doesn't give me much info to work with"? Really? It should tell you explicitly whether the error is 500.0 or 500.19, and from there you can move on. FRT can tell you more if you enable it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough information.Please add more details

Comment: It is returning a 500.19 error. Looking through the document right now.  Thanks.

Comment: If it is 500.19. Please check whether your IIS asp.net and .net extesnionsibility 3.5 module has been installed. And please enable detailed error message and post a error page screenshot. The screenshot for the error message is the key to fix this.

Comment: Hi, added screen shot of error message in original post.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JokiesDing Added the trace document

Comment: @Streamers. The error message show that you are placing an unsupported section in web.config. Please enabled detailed error message and access it from web browser. Then you will see which section is corrupted. You need to go to applicationhost.config to set OverrideModeDefault=Allow. If the section is not an IIS section. Then please ensure related extesion has been installed as I said before. Configuration manager can also help you figure out what configuration is supported in web.config in IIS.

Comment: @JokiesDing.  I appreciate your help.  I realize how lucky I have been on setting up my sites for the past few years now...never had any problems.  Here is the detailed error message.  See original post.

Comment: @Streamers I just update my assumption. Please check whether you publish in a virtual directory by mistake.

Comment: @JokiesDing.  Yikes, sometimes I just feel like an idiot.  I revisited the IIS installation on the server, and none of the .net development roles, etc. were installed.  I made sure a full iis install was setup and all works great.  Thank you to everyone who helped out!

Comment: HAHA... Never mind friend. I feel like you missed to install IIS feature when I see this case.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is you are hosting your web app in a folder by mistake. You didn't set  in the root web.config of your web-application or website. It looks just like you are hosting your application in a virtual directory or a sub-folder.

As you can see its only `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` is only supported by root web.config or applicationhost.config.

[image]

Modules section is not listed in folder(Vdir) level's web.config.

[image]

So please ensure you are publishing your application to a site's root folder or a sub application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/